# Libgdx Crashes upon execution. No error messages

Tags: java, libgdx

I create my project using the LibGDX setup tool and import it using eclipses, but when I test the project, without making any modifications, No windows pop up, and the program terminates.
I've tried both importing it as a Gradle and as a project.
I had the project working 1 week ago, but I cannot seem to get the project to run anymore.
Previous versions of LibGDX and Eclipse dont work either

Comment: It's probably something to do with your environment. Try reinstalling eclipse and download a new libgdx setup jar.

Comment: Forgot to mention. I've tried doing that to no avail. I've tried installing previous versions of LibGDX and Eclipse. I've also tried reinstalling my JDK.

Comment: Is it just libGDX? Have you tried to run other java programs on eclipse? A simple hello world will do too.

Comment: all programs work perfectly fine, even JFrames

Comment: I think I might've found the source of the problem, which is that my java virtual machine isn't being used while I execute the program. So I am going to have to reinstall that. That's the only observable difference I've found between my Mac, that does work, and my PC

Comment: The latest nVidia driver does not play nice with Java. Get their hotfix or roll back your driver.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you or not:

When you create your libGDX project, create it in folder that is NOT within the workspace folder you wish to use for Eclipse - that can cause quite a lot of unexpected results.

A basic setup as follows has always worked for me, first time, every time:

`C:\MyProjects\MyLibGdxProject\libGDX` <- Target folder for libGDX (not within Workspace)

`C:\MyProjects\MyLibGdxProject\workspace` <- Workspace for Eclipse